# Replicating rows based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below data frame

[image]

Now I want to transfer the data frame like below
[image]

I have used the python commands to do that but none of them worked . Could anyone please help me with how to do that
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.mas_id)].reset_index(drop=True)

n_df = pd.concat([df] * final_n)

newdf = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, final_n, axis=0))

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools` library's function `product`

```
from itertools import product

combi_rows = product(df.store.dropna(), df.mas_id.dropna())
new_df = pd.DataFrame(combi_rows, columns=df.columns)
```

Output

```
    store  mas_id
0   100.0       1
1   100.0       2
2   100.0       3
3   100.0       4
4   101.0       1
5   101.0       2
6   101.0       3
7   101.0       4
8   102.0       1
9   102.0       2
10  102.0       3
11  102.0       4
```

Edit:

If you want to sort by `mas_id` column,

```
new_df = new_df.sort_values('mas_id')
```

Output

```
    store  mas_id
0   100.0       1
4   101.0       1
8   102.0       1
1   100.0       2
5   101.0       2
9   102.0       2
2   100.0       3
6   101.0       3
10  102.0       3
3   100.0       4
7   101.0       4
11  102.0       4
```

Comment: I hope you understood how it works. @revathypartheeban

Answer (score 0):

You can the function `product` of `itertools`

```
import itertools

result = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df.store.unique(), df.mas_id.unique())),columns=df.columns)
```

and if you have nan values that you don't want to include just update it like this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df.store.dropna().unique(), df.mas_id.dropna().unique())),columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `how='cross'`:

```
(df.merge(df, how='cross', suffixes=('','2'))[['store2', 'mas_id']]
 .dropna().rename(columns={'store2': 'store'})
)
```

---

Yet another possible solution, based on [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {'store': np.tile(df.store.dropna(), len(df)),
     'mas_id': np.repeat(df.mas_id, len(df.store.dropna()))
     }
)
```

---

Output:

```
   store  mas_id
0  100.0       1
0  101.0       1
0  102.0       1
1  100.0       2
1  101.0       2
1  102.0       2
2  100.0       3
2  101.0       3
2  102.0       3
3  100.0       4
3  101.0       4
3  102.0       4
```